# Filter by type in Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

This SPARQL request looks for all cities called "Berlin" in Wikidata:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE {

  ?type (a | wdt:P279) wd:Q515. # Sub-type of city
  ?item wdt:P31 ?type.

  ?item rdfs:label "Berlin"@en.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

PROBLEM: It [returns zero result](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%3Ftype%20%28a%20%7C%20wdt%3AP279%29%20wd%3AQ515.%20%23%20Sub-type%20of%20city%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Ftype.%0A%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Berlin%22%40en.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D).

Meanwhile, the request below [correctly finds](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Berlin%22%40en.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fitem) Q64 (capital and city-state of Germany), but it also returns a lot of other things called Berlin, so I want to filter on cities *(then in a future phase I will order these cities by population, but that is outside the scope of this question)*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE {
  ?item rdfs:label "Berlin"@en.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

Note: My code for getting instances of subclasses of city (Berlin is a [big city](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1549591) which is subclass of [city](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q515)) seems to work correctly, as illustrated by the results of [this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FtypeLabel%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%3Ftype%20%28a%20%7C%20wdt%3AP279%29%20wd%3AQ515.%20%23%20Sub-type%20of%20city%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Ftype.%0A%0A%20%20%23%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Berlin%22%40en.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D).

Answer (score 4):

It was a Wikidata bug.

According to Wikidata's [Jura1](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/User:Jura1), it was a bug in Wikidata caused by someone's experiments with "preferred rank".

Discussion at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Project_chat/Archive/2016/09#P31_inconsistency

The bug has been fixed just now.

Comment: Ok, good that it works now. Just as a comment, you are asking for direct subclasses of city with your query. If you use SPARQL 1.1 property paths you could cover the case where an entity does not belong to a direct subclass of city.

Comment: @AKSW: Indeed, and from now on I will use this syntax to get all sub-classes recursively too: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/9743/754 Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can only query for data that is contained in the dataset.

If you try an alternative of your query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?type1 ?type2 WHERE {
  ?item rdfs:label "Berlin"@en.
  optional{?item rdf:type ?type1 }
  optional{?item wdt:P279 ?type2 }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

it returns no types, neither connected by `rdf:type` nor `wdt:P279`.

If you have a look at the [entity of the capital and city state Berlin](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q64), you can see that there is information about "instance of", but this property is supposed to be `https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31`. And none of them links to `wd:Q515`, I'm wondering from where you got this idea.

But to be honest, I don't know that much about Wikidata and to me, it's not clear why no `rdf:type` is used, but a common pattern for RDF datasets is to use

`?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* SUPER_CLASS .`

if we assume that there is `rdf:type` information available.

Comment: @whoever gave me the downvote: I'm happy with the downvote, but it would help me a lot if I could know the reason for, such that I can extend my knowledge and improve future answers.

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted. Note: Berlin is an instance of big city, which itself is a sub-class of city.

Comment: Thank's for the hint. I still have to learn more about the different entities that are used in Wikidata compared to good old RDF/RDFS like `rdf:type` or `rdfs:subClassOf`.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the types wd:Q64 is an instance of

```
SELECT DISTINCT   ?type  ?typeLabel WHERE {
wd:Q64 (a | wdt:P31) ?type.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?item
```

None of them are City (wd:Q515) or a sub-class of it.
Looks like a data issue. Perhaps you should contact Wikidata.

Comment: Berlin is an instance of big city, which itself is a sub-class of city. So I don't think there is any data issue.

Comment: Where are you seeing this?

Comment: Running the query above I get only 2 results neither of them is big city. (wd:Q1549591). Also running your original query with another city e.g. Boston I get the expected result. One of us is missing something obvious. Might be me.

Comment: Search for "big city" at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q64 then notice the "subclass of" at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1549591